# How to average the non-zero pixels of two images with slight offset [python]

Tags: python, panoramas

I have two greyscale images that have a slight offset (~80% overlap) that I need to average into a single image. The images have padding around them, so the overlap is already account for within the image (i.e. the x and y start position of each image is different). The images are aligned in their current offset, similar to a panoramic image.

My current approach (see below) is to use nested for loops, compare the pixel intensities at each position, sum them, and divide by the non-zero count.

```
    combined_image=np.empty((image1.shape))
    for row in range(image1.shape[0]):
        for pixel in range(image2.shape[1]):
            temp_array = np.array((image1[row][pixel], image2[row][pixel]))
            combined_image[row][pixel] = np.sum(temp_array)/np.count_nonzero(temp_array)
```

I believe it works, however, it is rather slow, as these images are 1000 x 1000 pixels. Was wondering if there is a more efficient approach

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you're using for loops with numpy, you're not taking advantage of its built-in functionality.

Use broadcast operations.

combined_image = (image1 + image2) / 2

Should be faster and definitely simpler